# Juniper SRX 240 - Routing subsystem not running on secondary node

Tags: routing, juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx

Does anyone know why rpd would not run on secondary node?

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

In a Juniper SRX Chassis Cluster, the master Routing Engine (RE) runs on only one node. This creates an active/passive control plane. All control plane processes (rpd, kmd, etc.) run only on the master RE.

From [Branch SRX Series and J Series Chassis Clustering](https://www.juniper.net/us/en/local/pdf/app-notes/3500132-en.pdf):

> The special redundancy group 0 refers to the status of the control
>   plane. In this example, node 0 is the primary node for this group and,
>   therefore, it is in charge of all control plane calculations (it acts
>   as the master RE and runs the control plane processes like rpd, kmd,
>   dhcpd, pppd, and others).

Comment: I'm just curious... I can configure SRX cluster for active/active state (which is not recommended by Juniper btw), and in this situation still the only one RP will be utilized?

Comment: Active/active in this context refers only to the data plane, not the control plane. It  simply means that both devices are actively passing traffic. There is still only one master Routing Engine, and the control plane daemons are running on only one node.

Comment: so when primary  node goes down secondary should take place but its not happening. I am testing the failover though rebooting the Primary node. Cluster setup correctly even I see secondary node becomes primary. do you have why ?

Comment: Can you update the question with the output of `show chassis cluster status` and `show configuration chassis cluster` and `show version` this will help with troubleshooting

Comment: Can you please suggest me the way to upload .txt file ?